# Smarter "Confirm File Replace" dialog on Windows

Tags: windows, comparison

In Windows (XP at least), when you drag a file to a folder that already has a file with the same name, you get a dialog like this:

[image]

Does anyone know of a replacement for that dialog that adds a *Compare* button (preferably configurable to use the comparison tool of my choice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a windows shell replacement you can't replace this as it is part of the windows shell.  This is called by an API and you can't supplement it.

Comment: Unfortunately, not the answer I was looking for, but thank you anyway.